# Send emails with translatable content using mailkit in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-core, mailkit

I'm looking for a way how to send emails with translatable content using mailkit in ASP.NET Core.

Is it possible to use XSLT/XML or should I use another solution?

Thanks in advance for any advice !

Comment: This question is extremely vague. What do you mean by "translatable content"? Why would it *not* be possible to use XSLT/XML with MailKit? I don't understand.

Comment: I would like to have content with variables that I can put my own translated text.

Comment: Of course you can do that. You just have to make the substitutions on your own (MailKit doesn't have APIs to do it).